# Was the Imam talking about Barzakh or Day of Judgment?

Tags: ramadan, day-of-judgement, barzakh

I read this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/when-people-die-do-they-go-directly-go-to-heaven-or-hell-till-judgement-day). I have often heard the Imam of my local mosque say the following:

1. During Ramdan and on the day of Eid, many people will be released from Hell by the mercy of Allah.
2. Also that, many people who die during a fast will enter Heaven.

Does this mean, people (sinners) who have passed away are spending time in Hell at present And good people are already spending time in Heaven? Please provide some clarity.

What I understand now is that, during the state of barzakh sinners will be punished by the angels (no to the extend as in Hell) and time will move very slowly for them until Judgment day. For the faithful believers, life in the state of barzakh will be pleasureful (not as pleasureful as in Heaven) and time will move very fast for them such that Judgment day will appear as tomorrow. Based on this, was the Imam actually talking about the mercy of Allah on Judgment day? Or was he talking about the state of barzakh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Imam is talking about receiving the mercy of Allah on the day of judgment. The residual period of the soul is in Barzakh or the veil or the astral spiritual world takes righteous souls to Wadi-us-Salam. For them , the time frame seizes and the Day of Judgment will appear as just one day between their physical death and that event.

Comment: Please consider adding references/evidences to support your claims.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, I think it is another way of mentioning what this hadith states:

> “At every breaking of the fast Allah has people whom He frees (from the Fire), and that happens every night.” ([Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1317130))

This hadith according to Darussalam is Hasan. And I think its meaning is similar to the hadith mentioned in Sahih al-Bukhari:

> "Whoever observes fasts during the month of Ramadan out of sincere faith, and hoping to attain Allah's rewards, then all his past sins will be forgiven." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/31))

Basically, the meaning may be that Ramadan provides an opportunity for sinful people to get their sins forgiven and thus free themselves from the punishment. Meaning that their previous actions would have brought them to Hell but Ramadan caused their sins to be forgiven.

As for the second statement, I don't know the source for it regarding fasting specifically. However, it is possible for (some of) the souls of believers to enter Paradise but that is without the complete body they will be given after the Day of Judgement. This can be known from [this](https://sunnah.com/urn/1344110) and [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/181) hadith.